# Session downloading from webclient or webbrowser(.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

I am having an issue regarding downloading of pdf file from this page for example:

https://publicaccess.solihull.gov.uk/online-applications/applicationDetails.do?activeTab=documents&keyVal=OPQ691OEKGD00

You could see in that page there is an "Application Form" which the last column of it has a pdf link. I can already parse the link for pdf using HtmlAgilityPack but the problem is when I do this for the pdf link

            `WebBrowser1.Navigate(docUrl)
            While (WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            End While
                Dim client As New WebClient

                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie)
                client.DownloadFile(New Uri(pdfLink), "appForm.pdf")`

It just return 404. This could be possibly a session based page though the pdf link is not changing. As for the headers, I see that WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie returns null even the page just finished loading. Is there any alternative that I can do for this?

Here is the pdf link by the way. You may try to directly open it without clicking the page to see the problem

https://publicaccess.solihull.gov.uk/online-applications/files/B30089CDFBE1BBCC3D0E7A598DEFEA61/pdf/PL_2017_01205_PPRM-APPLICATION_FORM_NO_PERSONAL_DATA-711302.pdf

Comment: You don't need `WebBrowser`.

Comment: @Xaqron Then how can I download the pdf since it returns 404 when I just directly download it? It seems I am having an issue regarding to the session of the page

Comment: Did you try to open a pdf without opening the page? Try to open a fresh incognito and paste the pdf link there. It will appear as a Document Unavailable. That is my issue here

Comment: I have failed with your new link. If you need `cookies` just make a request to the page and use the same client for actual downloading.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue. The link isn't changing but without opening a session from the page where it came from, making it to be failed. So what should I do about that?

Comment: That is what I am asking for. How should I do that given that I am only using WebBrowser and WebClient. How can I transfer the session/cookies from webbrowser to webclient and webbrowser cookies returns null

Comment: You don't need that heavy object (WebBrowser) just for obtaining cookies. Use enhanced `WebClient` from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This a cookie aware WebCLient. Credit goes to [Pavel Savara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129124/pavel-savara).

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{

    public WebClientEx() // Added to original code
    {
        this.container = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public WebClientEx(CookieContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer
        {
            get { return container; }
            set { container= value; }
        }

    private CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest r = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        var request = r as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = container;
        }
        return r;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
        ReadCookies(response);
        return response;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        ReadCookies(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void ReadCookies(WebResponse r)
    {
        var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
            container.Add(cookies);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use directly the pdf link here? And where the parameters for the constructor will come from?

Comment: This `WebClient` remember `cookies` from previous call(s). First visit the parent page and then using the same client request the pdf file. Constructor take a `CookieContainer` if there exist anyone. I will modify it so you can use it without passing one.

Comment: I just tried putting a new CookieContainer there and it works! Thank you so much for this!!!